# What musical instrument does Iroh play?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

We see Uncle Iroh play this peaceful musical instrument periodically throughout the *Avatar: The Last Airbender* series...

[image]

What is the in-universe name of this instrument and what real instrument is played to make the sound?

Comment: I love how the edit contains the answer (in the video title) :D

Comment: @Kevin - It's unfortunate :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The in-universe name is the "[Tsungi Horn](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Tsungi_horn)" (also referred to as a Tsunghi horn and a Sungi Horn, depending on who was being interviewed)

> **Zuko**: *For the last time, I'm not playing the tsungi horn!*
>
> **Iroh**: *No, it's about our plans. There's a bit of a problem.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Waterbending Master](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Transcript:The_Waterbending_Master)</sup></sub>

---

In reality, the makers of the show used a mixture of [Armenian duduk music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSnNoEA1y3A&feature=youtu.be&t=1m13s) and a [Western trombone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBbYdpRUnxE&feature=youtu.be&t=1m12s) to make the sounds from this fictitious instrument.

> **JZ:** *Uncle Iroh's sunghi horn piece turned out to be pretty effective. That was another interesting challenge since the sunghi
> horn is a fictitious instrument. We had to invent a new instrument
> without letting it sound modern and computerized. Ironically, we wound
> up using a music synthesis technique called convolution to impose
> characteristics of a trombone onto the duduk. I think the result
> sounds very much like an acoustic instrument which is part reed and
> part brass.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Music Interview with the Track Team](http://www.avatarspirit.net/interviews.php?id=4)</sup></sub>

Comment: +1 Interesting. I don't really hear any trombone mixed in. I believe you and think you're right. Just don't hear the bone. I definitely guessed it was some sort of reed instrument.

Comment: @iMerchant - I think what they're driving at is that they superimposed the Duduk music onto a synthesiser capable of doing fast [glissandos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHH5JUQW6gQ), something that the Duduk absolutely can't do.

Comment: Gotcha. They made it so u can "slide" the notes up & down like a bone. +1 for teaching a new word (glissandos).

Comment: The show quote and the interview use different spellings ("tsungi" vs "sunghi"). Are there two acceptable spellings or is one of them in error?

Comment: @Thunderforge - There's a quote on one of the avatar boards, allegedly from one of the production team. *"[T]he tsungi horn had to be a cross between a woodwind and a brass instrument. we played that theme on a duduk (armenian reed instrument) and then performed a computer process called convolution where we combined the timbre of a trombone with our duduk performance."*. So the most likely correct spelling is tsungi, although I've seen it spelled variously. The quote above is presumably a transcription, rather than an online interview